# java Calendar.getInstance() Getting system datetime error

Tags: java, datetime, mocking

I run below code but it returns 1 year later date

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMMdd_HHmmssSSS").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())

System.out.println(timeStamp);
```

output:

```
20171228_112248995
```

but it should be as below:

```
20161228_112248995
```

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/xoCNty). (And what does this have to do with [tag:mocking]?)

Comment: What is your computer’s clock set to?

Comment: works for me too...!!

Comment: As I see in right bottom corner the system time is correct

Comment: As I see in right bottom corner the system time is correct but the output of script is wrong.

Comment: Does the bottom right corner of your screen display year? And/or weekday? If the computer clock was set one year ahead of time by mistake (or for some unrelated reason), the screen corner would still show correct time, month and day of month. But year and weekday would not be correct.